# How to pass directory path as arguments from command line using perl?

Tags: perl

---

My question as follows:

I struck with how to pass the command line arguments instead of passing directory path using perl .

Example suppose if am executing the file as follows:

```
./welcome.pl -output_dir "/home/data/output"
```

My code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use Getopt::Long 'GetOptions';
GetOptions(
          'output=s'  => \my $output_dir,

); 
my $location_dir="/home/data/output";
print $location_dir;
```

Code explanation:

I tried to print the contents in the $output_dir.so i need to pass the command line arguments inside the variable (i.e `$location_dir`) instead of passing path directly how can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use File::Basename qw( basename );
use Getopt::Long   qw( GetOptions );

sub usage {
   if (@_) {
      my ($msg) = @_;
      chomp($msg);
      print(STDERR "$msg\n");
   }

   my $prog = basename($0);
   print(STDERR "$prog --help for usage\n");
   exit(1);
}

sub help {
   my $prog = basename($0);
   print(STDERR "$prog [options] --output output_dir\n");
   print(STDERR "$prog --help\n");
   exit(0);
}

Getopt::Long::Configure(qw( posix_default ));  # Optional, but makes the argument-handling consistent with other programs.
GetOptions(
    'help|h|?' => \&help,
    'output=s' => \my $location_dir,
)
    or usage();

defined($location_dir)
    or usage("--output option is required\n");

print("$location_dir\n");
```

Or course, if the argument is indeed required, then why not just use `./welcome.pl "/home/data/output"` instead of an not-really optional parameter.

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use File::Basename qw( basename );
use Getopt::Long   qw( GetOptions );

sub usage {
   if (@_) {
      my ($msg) = @_;
      chomp($msg);
      print(STDERR "$msg\n");
   }

   my $prog = basename($0);
   print(STDERR "$prog --help for usage\n");
   exit(1);
}

sub help {
   my $prog = basename($0);
   print(STDERR "$prog [options] [--] output_dir\n");
   print(STDERR "$prog --help\n");
   exit(0);
}

Getopt::Long::Configure(qw( posix_default ));  # Optional, but makes the argument-handling consistent with other programs.
GetOptions(
    'help|h|?' => \&help,
)
    or usage();

@ARGV == 1
    or usage("Incorrect number of arguments\n");

my ($location_dir) = @ARGV;

print("$location_dir\n");
```

Comment: Can you explain me why you had used help option @ikegami

Comment: Didn't have to. But I felt it was better than putting `print(STDERR "Ask user "find data" on StackOverflow for usage\n");` in `usage()` :)